# Usage of "Revised Document"

Tags: meaning, expressions, names

I offer two Word templates and recommend to use one of them in order to get a well-designed document.

Using the expression `revised document` is correct in this case?

For example:  `It is recommended to select the first template in order to get the most 
revised document; The first template offers a cover page and automatic numbering of 
chapters and pages.`

Any other ideas?

Comment: no, "most revised document" does not make sense. You'd have to explain what you mean.

Comment: @JoeBlow, Thanks, I mean to describe a document that is well-designed. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "most up-to-date" or "best formatted" document set-up?

Comment: @ErikKowal, Thanks. I mean "Best formatted". What is the 'best formatted' word to pronounce it?

Comment: I don't understand your use of the term 'pronounce it'. To pronounce something means to physically say it. Do you simply mean 'express it' (in other words, 'convey its meaning')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Select the first template for a well-designed document; The first
>   template offers a cover page and automatic numbering of chapters and
>   pages.

or

> It is recommended to select the first template in order to get a
>   well-designed document; The first template offers a cover page and
>   automatic numbering of  chapters and pages.

forget 'revision' here

Comment: Thanks, Is `well-designed` is enough? Isn't there a word that pronounce this meaning?